# Rust: How do I convert/read a BytesMut to a file?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a value of type `BytesMut` (from [bytes](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.5.4/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html))

The source of this value is a file that I have downloaded from a remote source (an AWS S3 bucket, in this case). 
I want to store(write) these bytes (it's an image) to a file so that I can then go ahead and read the image file, do some processing, etc.

What's the best/easiest way to do this?

I've taken a look at this [question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-use-bytes-bytesmut-correctly/35817), but it hasn't helped me as I think it's doing the reverse of what I'm attempting.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A `BytesMut` derefs into a slice, so you can access its whole contents with `&b[..]`.  Is `File::create("filename").write_all(&b[..])?` what you're looking for?

Comment: It would be useful to see the relevant part of your code. There are a few things that are unclear to me, e.g. why to you want to write the data to disk if you just want to read it again? If you need to write the data to disk for some reason, why do you download it to memory first, instead of directly streaming it to a file? If the file isn't too big, non of this really matters, but in any case sharing the actual code usually results in more useful answers.

Comment: Yes @user4815162342 That works, thank you so much! 
I used `as_ref()` to convert it to a &[u8] and then I could write it to a file.

Comment: @SvenMarnach those are good questions, I'm trying to figure out the answer to them myself, now. Thanks for pointing that stuff out. 
I already have existing functions, using a different library, in another module, that accepts a path to an image and then reads it in. 
Maybe for the sake of separation of concerns, I would do this. Although, it does have some overheads and would require me to delete each file I download, after I'm done (as I would expect this code to handle thousands of images).

Comment: @KahlilAbreu It sounds like the function reading an image should accept and implementation of `Read` (or maybe `AsyncRead`) instead of a path. This would allow you to pass either a file object or a buffer object, or even the data stream of the HTTP connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BytesMut` derefs into a [slice of `u8`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.5.4/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html#impl-Deref), so you can access its whole contents with `&b[..]`. To write it to a file, use the `write_all` method on `Write` values, which accepts a slice:

```
let b: BytesMut = ...;
File::create("filename").write_all(&b[..])?;
```